# Rails expect(controller).not_to have_received(:get_from_database) not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rspec

I'm trying to test caching in my app by checking if the function that hit the database is being called.

My controller:

```
class MyApp::MyController < MyApp::BaseController
    def index
      @cache_key = "testkeydd"
      @current_time = Time.current
      @data = Rails.cache.fetch(@cache_key, expires_in: 1.hour) do
        get_from_database
      end
    end

    def get_from_database
      puts "============DATABASE HIT============"
      Data.last(20)
    end
end
```

My spec:

```
describe MyApp::MyController, type: :controller do
        let(:memory_store) { ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:memory_store) }

        before :each do
            allow(Rails).to receive(:cache).and_return(memory_store)
            Rails.cache.clear
            allow(controller).to receive(:get_from_database).and_call_original
        end

        describe 'GET /myroute' do

            it 'hits the database after creating a new booking' do
                get :index, format: :json #First request
                expect(controller).to have_received(:get_from_database) #Passes

                get :index, format: :json #Second request
                expect(controller).not_to have_received(:get_from_database) #Fails
            end
        end
end
```

When I run the spec the function `get_from_database` is only called on the first request and not on the second request.

Do you would expect the test to pass. However `expect(controller).not_to have_received(:get_from_database)` fails with:

```
   expected: 0 times with any arguments
   received: 1 time
```

Comment: Rails caching is enabled in test env?

Comment: @SampatBadhe `memory_store`

Answer (score 0):

The default numbers of expectation is one, so you should be fine setting a single expectation, and doing two requests.

Try:

```
it 'hits the database after creating a new booking' do
  expect(controller).to have_received(:get_from_database)
  get :index, format: :json #First request
  get :index, format: :json #Second request
end
```

Also, in your case it'd be more clear to test that whatever returns `get_from_database` is cached, so you could do something like `expect(Rails.cache.fetch(...)).to eq(...)`, and that would cover the case without RSpec spies.

Comment: i think OP'purpose is test that the db is hit only one time (`fetch`), so it's better to explicitly expect `.once` as well as change test case description `hits the database at the first time ...` ( or 2 test cases ?)

Comment: @LamPhan You are correct. I want to test if the db is hit only the first time i call the method. I don't understand what you mean with so it's better  to explicitly expect .once. Can you give an example?

Comment: @StarMan https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts

Comment: @LamPhan Thank you this seems to work as expected